# Topic Distribution over time LDA (months

Tags: jupyter-notebook, distribution, lda, timeline, topic-modeling

I have build a topic model through gensim and I was also able to analyse it with the pyLDAvis. However, I am wondering if it is possible to visualize the distribution of topics over the whole time of the data collection.

The result should be a line diagram, that starts with the first month and the probability of the topic and ends with the last month.
it would be great if this would also be possible with i.e. 3-5 topics visualized in one diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There are some topic models, like DTM (Blei and Lafferty), eDTM (Dieng, Blei et al.), (DTM = dynamic topic model), and Topics over Time (Wang and McCallum) that are temporal topic models that can achieve something similar to what you want.  If you have a large data set, these models are less feasible because they take a lot of time to run.  In that case, your best bet would be to partition your data set into time periods and run LDA for each time period.  A good temporal topic model that works at scale is something of an unsolved problem.